# Live Rotation of SCNNode

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, core-motion, cmmotionmanager

I want my node to rotate on the Y axis while the camera is rotating.

```
class ArtScene: SCNScene{

    var image = UIImage()
    var geometry = SCNBox()
    var motion = MotionKit()
    var node = SCNNode()


    convenience init(create: Bool) {
        self.init()

        image = UIImage(named: "sf")!
        let lenght: CGFloat = 50
        let width: CGFloat = self.image.size.width
        let height: CGFloat = self.image.size.height
        self.geometry = SCNBox(width: width / 1000 , height: height / 1000, length: lenght / 1000, chamferRadius: 0.005)

        print("Geometry WIDTH: \(self.geometry.width)")
        print("Geometry LENGHT: \(self.geometry.length)")

        self.geometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red
        self.geometry.firstMaterial?.specular.contents = UIColor.white
        self.geometry.firstMaterial?.emission.contents = UIColor.blue
        node = SCNNode(geometry: self.geometry)
        self.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
   }

func rotate() {
    motion.getDeviceMotionObject { (deviceMotion) in
        let rotationY = deviceMotion.rotationRate.y
        print(rotationY)
        let rotationAction =   SCNAction.rotate(by: CGFloat(1.0), around: SCNVector3(0,rotationY,0), duration: 2.0)
        self.node.runAction(rotationAction)
    }
}
```

}

I can print the Device motion, but can't get the node to rotate at the same time. How can I do it?